Bluetooth malformed MSFT vendor event
EDIT:
Disabled "Switchable graphics", but left "discrete graphics mode" enabled in bios. This solved LSPCON error.
Now these are the errors
Ubuntu 22.04
i7-10th 5.1GHz 64GB NVIDIA Quadro T1000
Previous answers here relate to a full hard drive, mine is not full. I estimate the OS drive to have 50% free space.
Boot fails. I am unable to access the journal or TTY or type anything in the terminal.
Errors here
and also here
This is a new laptop, ubuntu has been running fine for a few days. I ask for help because I want to know if this is a hardware issue, my warranty is still active and worried if I just reinstall and this happens out of warranty.
